# How to show screen recording permission prompt again?

Tags: permissions, video-recording

Android asks for permission before an app records screen as following (a standard Android feature, not a part of the app):
[image]

After I select "Don't show again", this prompt will not show up as expected.  How can I bring it back for this app without uninstalling and reinstalling it?

I have checked App permissions, but it is not there. I have also deleted the app's cache to no avail.

**[Edit] 2016-07-08**
The following screenshot shows all the permissions (no screen record/capture permission):
[image]

The following screenshot shows the permissions of the app:
[image]

Comment: Don't have enough rep to answer this, but "appops set PACKAGE_NAME_HERE PROJECT_MEDIA ignore" removes the permission

Answer (score 1):

it seems there is no way to do that without uninstalling app or restarting permissions [Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

but if you want to restart the permissions
Go to `Application Manager` -> `App Permissions` -> `Requested Permission` -> turn it off / on for your program .

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  I could not find Application Manager.  The Android device (Android 5.1) has "App permissions". It has a list of permissions requested by apps. I do not see the request for screen recording.

Comment: are you sure `screen Recording` isn't listed under additional permissions ?

Comment: I have just added screenshots to show no "screen recording".

Answer (score 1):

Clear app data to remove granted permissions of the screen recording app.

Comment: Where does it say that clearing *app data* removes granted permissions? Can you back that by a source? I very much doubt this.

Comment: @Izzy It does so, since clearing data == using the app from scratch and so Android does revoke the permissions. In Marshmallow, you can see it for yourself in the permission tab of the app.

Comment: @Firelord That restriction (MM and up) wasn't mentioned – it was phrased "generic" :) Plus, while at splitting hair: it would remove other things as well even before MM – e.g. all the settings adjusted. So [Koorosh's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/150343/16575) is a much better approach. And, seeing the first comment on it, OP states being on LP (5.1) – a comment made almost a year before this answer was posted.

Comment: MM and up is implied since MM added the ability to control specific permissions. Prior to MM an app just got all the permissions that were presented to the user at install time.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
<sup>click image for larger variant</sup>

On the bottom right is where you go to Show System Processes. I came here looking for the answer and ended up figuring it out so figured I'd post the right way since I had the same problem and was initially getting the same results until doing this.

Comment: And what does this have to do with "showing permissions dialog again"? I'm a bit confused. Maybe the confusion is you're talking about the "Screen recording" app (which is a pre-installed system app with Android 6+ AFAIK) – while OP asked about the screen recording permission of some user-installed app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall this app after uninstalling it from your device and you will start seeing this permission prompt again. I tried this on my Android device running Marshmallow 6.0.1 and it did the job.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  My original post asked specifically for how to remedy this "without uninstalling and reinstalling it".

Answer (score 0):

I Found the screen recorder permissions after tapping on the menu icon at the bottom of each function's Permission page. In other words, I opened the permissions list for Storage, tapped on the menu icon, tapped on the show system link that came up and found the video clip recorder app towards the bottom of the list, then finally disabled it for Storage. I then repeated the same process for Microphone and Phone. Cheers. Marco